# R Markdown - Reference Section Numbers in PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using R Markdown in R Studio and have a number of sections.  I am attempting to reference the section number using a custom section reference label as documented here:  https://ulyngs.github.io/oxforddown/cites-and-refs.html but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is some sample code:

```
Some paragraph text here

## Obtain Projected {#Projections}

Another paragraph with a reference to Section Number \@ref(Projections).
```

I'm hoping for the second paragraph to be rendered as:

"Another paragraph with a reference to Section Number 3.1." for example.

My relevant YAML headers are:

```
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \def\tightlist{}
  \setlength\parindent{24pt}
output: rticles::tf_article
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out shortly after posting, so sorry to post my own answer.  I simply had to add `bookdown` to the my YAML section:

```
---
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \def\tightlist{}
  \setlength\parindent{24pt}
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::tf_article
---
```

And then this worked:

Some paragraph text here

`## Obtain Projected {#Projections}`

`Another paragraph with a reference to Section Number \@ref(Projections).`